# Missing Package pr2_mechanism_msgs in pr2_mechanism stack

Tags: pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running ROS Fuerte and Ubuntu 12.04.  I downloaded the stack "pr2_mechanism" using the mercurial repository listed [here](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism?distro=fuerte).  The command I executed was:

> $ hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/pr2mechanism/hg pr2_mechanism

When I try to compile package "pr2_mechanism_diagnostics" within this stack, I get the following error:

> Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack deps-manifests pr2_mechanism_diagnostics
> [rospack] Error: package/stack pr2_mechanism_diagnostics depends on non-existent package pr2_mechanism_msgs

The package "pr2_mechanism_msgs" should be in the stack "pr2_mechanism" since it [appears](https://kforge.ros.org/pr2mechanism/hg/file/09796e982a22/pr2_mechanism_msgs) in the repository's web interface.  However, the package is not included when I clone this repository using the command above. The only packages included are:

1. pr2_controller_interface
2. pr2_controller_manager
3. pr2_hardware_interface
4. pr2_mechanism_diagnostics
5. pr2_mechanism_model
6. realtime_tools

Why is pr2_mechanism_msgs missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48992/missing-package-pr2_mechanism_msgs-in-pr2_mechanism-stack/) by [liangfok](https://answers.ros.org/users/1811/liangfok/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2012-11-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why are you installing from source? Just take the debian package:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-pr2-mechanism
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liangfok](https://answers.ros.org/users/1811/liangfok/) on 2012-11-24**:
Thanks.  I did not know there was a pre-built debian package available.